# Escape defined special characters from string

Tags: c#, regex, escaping

I am using Regex.escape to escape some of the pre-defined special characters by escape function now i have requirement to escape below special characters which are not supported (some of them) by Regex.escape, is their any function available for same ?

```
Regex.escape

List of escape characters : + - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /
```

Can i use string.Replace for same, i am able to replace one character at at time but all character can i check and replace ?

```
Input = eFiled_20061010-01-0021-002_signed (09.30.10)(APN).pdf
Output = eFiled_20061010\\-01\\-0021\\-002_signed\\ \\(09.30.10\\)\\(APN\\).pdf
```

Comment: Try `Regex.Replace(s, @"[][+&|!(){}^""~*?:\\/-]", "\\$&")`. Why did you write `&&` and `||`? Should single `&` and `|` be escaped or only doubled? Please provide more details if the line of code above is not what you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : I want to escape space as well.

Comment: Well, add it - `Regex.Replace(s, @"[][+&|!(){}^""~*?: \\/-]", "\\$&")` ([demo](https://ideone.com/l4j0zm)).

Comment: What about double `|` and `&`? You have not clarified that.

Comment: && and || should be escaped

Comment: How? What is the expected result for `&|=&&||` string?

Comment: I dont have example right now, i was given set of special characters that need to be escaped..i will get back to you on this. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you seem to have a list of multicharacter strings, too, not just  symbols.

Comment: The point is, do you want `&&` to be escaped as `\\&&` or `\\&\\&`?. Same question for `||`.

Comment: See also https://ideone.com/GnVl5z - I added a second way to escape only double `|` and `&`. It can be adjusted with lookarounds if needed (if you need to avoid doing anything to `||||` or `&&&`).

Comment: @user662285 Any feedback?

Comment: I am facing a different issue..can you help me with it ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I have few records for modified date which is null so the code breaks when any modifieddate is null..how to handle this in below code -  public DateTime? modifiedDate { get; set; }  

var lst = outObject.response.docs.Select(b => 
            new finalOutput {modifiedDate = b.last_modified[0]}).ToList<finalOutput>();

Comment: This is not how things work on SO. Let's finish the current question. What works for you?

Comment: Sorry i did not mean that...I mean business is checking whether to put && and || in the list or not..so they will take decision and let us know.I will let you know as soon as i hear from them

Comment: As for that code, you need to add some check for null. Sorry, I cannot repro, I do not have your code.

Comment: Here is my code - public DateTime? modifiedDate { get; set; } var lst = outObject.response.docs.Select(b => new finalOutput {modifiedDate = b.last_modified[0]}).ToList<finalOutput>();  -- i added null check but it did not work - modifiedDate = b.last_modified[0].HasValue ? b.last_modified[0] : DateTime.Now -- gives error as OBject reference not set

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181178/discussion-between-user662285-and-wiktor-stribizew).